# Keeping a div in the top right of a container with multiple flexbox items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm attempting to use flexbox to arrange a series of various items within a container, but cannot seem to properly "pin" a div to the top-right of this container.

Before wrapping, all is well and good:
[image]

However, after wrapping, it is brought down a row:
[image: after wrap]

The relevant CSS styles for all of the elements here are (class names modified for simplicity):

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 3em !important;
}
.teal-items {
    margin: 0.25em;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 36px;
}
.shove-this-in-the-top-right {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: .5em;
}
```

I tried giving `shove-this-in-the-top-right` an implicit `display` of block, inline, or inline-block, to no avail.

Comment: if it's in the same container, no way forget it ... the easy solution is to make it in it's own container OR combine many CSS and workaround

Comment: What do you mean make it in its own container @TemaniAfif ?

Comment: get it out the actualt cotnainer .. so you will have the main container with all the item then this element outside at the right

Comment: I'm not too sure I can necessarily do that due to design limitations.  Is there any other way?

Comment: @NoahOvercash Take a look on my solution, there is one way with the container, which was explained here in the comments and one way without container and pseudo element after.

Comment: @NoahOvercash PS: For the next time, please provide us also you're html. It is a quit interessting and good question, but just the CSS isn't enough, maybe that's the reason why someone put a downvote on this :)

Comment: @MrBuggy Alright, I thought because it was mostly just `div`s it wasn't needed.  Will do in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible solutions, how to solve this. The first one is to use a wrapper for the floated items and a wrapper for the fixed one. This would be a clear solution.

The second solution is to work with the pseudo element `::after`. You can float the items again in a wrapper and give it a fixed `width`. Then use pseudo element `::after` to position the fixed item on right top using `position` `relative` and `absolute`. This could also be a possible solution. Take a look on the snippets, I have separated the solutions with comments:

```css
/* FIRST SOLUTION WITH WRAPPER FOR FIXED ITEM */

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.container__items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap
}

.container--fixed {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.container--fixed .container__item {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.container__item {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: lightcoral;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}


/* SECOND SOLUTION WITH PSEUDO AFTER */

.container--second {
  position: relative;
}

.container--second .container__items {
  width: 400px;
}

.container--second::after {
  content: "Fixed item";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!-- FIRST SOLUTION WITH WRAPPER FOR FIXED ITEM -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__items">
    <div class="container__item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="container__item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="container__item">Item 3</div>
    <div class="container__item">Item 4</div>
    <div class="container__item">Item 5</div>
    <div class="container__item">Item 6</div>
    <div class="container__item">Item 7</div>
    <div class="container__item">Item 8</div>
    <div class="container__item">Item 9</div>
    <div class="container__item">Item 10</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container--fixed">
    <div class="container__item">Fixed item</div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- SECOND SOLUTION WITH PSEUDO AFTER -->
<div class="container container--second">
  <div class="container__items">
    <div class="container__item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="container__item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="container__item">Item 3</div>
    <div class="container__item">Item 4</div>
    <div class="container__item">Item 5</div>
    <div class="container__item">Item 6</div>
    <div class="container__item">Item 7</div>
    <div class="container__item">Item 8</div>
    <div class="container__item">Item 9</div>
    <div class="container__item">Item 10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Alright thanks, hadn't thought of using the ::after selector.

Comment: @NoahOvercash I think it's the only way if you want to do this without an wrapper for the fixed element :) thanks for the mark, cheers

Comment: @NoahOvercash as a side note, there is no need for pseudo element you can do it with your actual element already present in the container

Comment: @NoahOvercash You can make a jsFiddle or codepen and put it here in the comment :)

Comment: I would but you gave a great answer with a fiddle so I think that need's covered!